# Css set table td border based on max length content

Tags: html, css

I have simple table with 3 columns.

```html
 

   <table>
<thead>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Desc</th>
<th></th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="attrCodeTd">Short text</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="attrCodeTd">Short text</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="attrCodeTd">Long text ......................................End long text</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>

<tbody>

</table>
```

How can i set border left for second column based on max content length of this column?

It is my screenshot : https://clip2net.com/s/46HwEzS
And  jsfiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/aum84sfb/1/

So border-left must be dinamicaly, based on content. 
How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: Just ran your code an it works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/3axpgoc4/

Comment: please look at this : https://jsfiddle.net/aum84sfb/1/
need border right for td with class .attrCodeTd based on max length content

Comment: You want a border for the second column takes up the whole height ?

Comment: yes, please look on my screenshot

Comment: The screenshot is not clear, Can you make a better illustration ?

Comment: please look: https://clip2net.com/s/46HyxkV
i mean that width for column is not fix

Comment: i think you need to remove the `right padding` if you are using any. Also you can remove any fixed width if you are using any. Normally tr will hold the max content width as it's own width. And you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: Alright you'll have to provide more context because after the first column comes the second and from your screenshot there seems to be some fixed amount of width that's making the first column be wider than it should be

Comment: Here you can see that it's showing fine https://prnt.sc/rovej2

Comment: @AnastasiaZavizion you can assign `width` to your table and later you can assign indiviual `width` for the columns so that the width will be fixed.

Comment: tell me this, what should happen when the content increased 3 times the what you have listed? whether it should wrap that content to next line or it should increase the width in the same line?